# Scrolling on mobile not working with WordPress Page

Tags: css, wordpress

Photography website (www.jyiphoto.com) with portfolio and text based pages.

Text based pages (blog, about, testimonials) do not scroll on mobile. Work on desktop and Chrome desktop's simulated mobile.

Tried adding overflow auto and disabling plugins.

```
    /* =============================================================================
   CSS Reset
   ========================================================================== */

html, body, div, span, applet, object, iframe,
h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, p, blockquote, pre,
a, abbr, acronym, address, big, cite, code,
del, dfn, em, font, img, ins, kbd, q, s, samp,
small, strike, strong, sub, sup, tt, var,
b, u, i, center,
dl, dt, dd, ol, ul, li,
fieldset, form, label, legend,
table, caption, tbody, tfoot, thead, tr, th, td {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    border: 0;
    outline: 0;
    font-size: 100%;
    vertical-align: baseline;
    background: transparent;
}

html { font-size: 100%; -webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%; -ms-text-size-adjust: 100%; /*-webkit-font-smoothing: subpixel-antialiased;*/ }

body {
    line-height: 1;
    /*text-rendering:optimizeLegibility;*/
    overflow: visible;
}

html body {
    overflow: visible;
}

ol, ul {
    list-style: none;
}
blockquote, q {
    quotes: none;
}
blockquote:before, blockquote:after,
q:before, q:after {
    content: '';
    content: none;
}

:focus {
    outline: 0;
}

ins {
    text-decoration: none;
}
del {
    text-decoration: line-through;
}

/* tables still need 'cellspacing="0"' in the markup */
table {
    border-collapse: collapse;
    border-spacing: 0;
}
td { vertical-align: top; }
img{max-width:100%;}

img { border: 0; -ms-interpolation-mode: bicubic; vertical-align: middle;}

svg:not(:root) { overflow: hidden; }

figure { margin: 0; }

input:valid, textarea:valid {  }
input:invalid, textarea:invalid { }
input[type="text"],input[type="submit"], textarea { -webkit-appearance: none; -webkit-border-radius:0px; }

.chromeframe { margin: 0.2em 0; background: #ccc; color: black; padding: 0.2em 0; }

::selection         {background: #dd3333; color: #fff; }
::-moz-selection    {background: rgb(255,255,158);}
img::selection      {background: transparent;}
img::-moz-selection {background: transparent;}
```

=========================================================================
                                         LAYOUTS
       ========================================================================= */

```
/* ======================
    Global
   ====================== */
html {
    padding: 0px !important;
}
html,body {
    position: relative;
    height: 100%;
}
#main, .ajaxable {
    min-height: 100.1%;
}
.page-template-full-screen-page-php #main ,
.page-template-full-screen-page-php .ajaxable {
    min-height: initial !important;
}
```

Hoping to get mobile scrolling back.

Comment: Trying adding a touch swipe event for images for mobile

Comment: deactivate the plugin if you have installed in worpdress